# $G$ is a cyclic group of order $30$ generated by $a$. Find the subgroup $H$ of order $6$.Find the generators of $H$

Tags: group-theory

I have tried to write $G=\left \{i,a,a^2,.......,a^{29}\right \}$ where $a$ is the generator of $G$.
Now $30$ is divisible by $6$. Then $a^{30/6}=a^5$ is of order $6$.
How to progress next?

Comment: now generate. let $b=a^5$, take $i, b, b^2, \ldots$

Comment: OK, so $H = \{1, a^5, a^{10}, a^{15}, a^{20}, a^{25}\}$. Or, writing $b = a^5$, simply $H = \{1, b, b^2, b^3, b^4, b^5\}$. The generators are precisely those $b^k$ where $k$ is coprime to $6$.

Comment: So the generator is is a^5.. and the subgroup is H={1,a^5,a^10,a^15,a^20,a^25}

Comment: $a^5$ is one generator. There is one more.

Comment: It is a^25 I know. But how we may find that there are two generators?

Comment: Do you mean, how do we know there are not more than two? Refer to my previous comment: $b^k$ is a generator of $\langle b \rangle$ if and only if $k$ and $|\langle b \rangle|$ are relatively prime. In this case, $k=1$ and $k=5$ are relatively prime to $6$, but $k=0,2,3,4$ are not.

Comment: No I'm asking that how can we get to know that there are two generators not only one!?

Comment: Oh, I see. Note that we always have $\langle g \rangle = \langle g^{-1} \rangle$ for any element $g$ of any group. So as long as $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are not equal, a cyclic group $\langle g \rangle$ has at least two generators.

Comment: Oh I got you @bungo

Comment: As a^25 is the inverse element of 1

Comment: $a^{25} = a^{-5}$ is the inverse element of $a^5$.